# eclipse try to access svn information stored in keychain

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I m using eclipse luna in Mac with subclipse + subversion  and have an annoying popUp each time i try to synchronise my project from svn.
Pop Message :

> eclipse try to access svn information stored in svn://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX XXXX
>        XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX- in your keychain. ???

I don't use any master password and i've cleared all stored password in eclipse but luck.

Maybe a a new issue in eclipse luna ?

Answer (score 0):

SVN itself does its own credentials caching and on OS X it will do that in the OS X keychain.  There are some settings you can edit in ~/.subversion/config and servers text files to turn this off, but it is on by default.

Comment: svn cache  on OS X keychain ? i m note sure ... if configured maybe ,  i can edit config files under .subversion folder to allow it ,.... but i m talking about Eclipse application, not default svn client MacOSX

Comment: Subclipse uses the same SVN libraries as the svn command line client, so the behavior is the same.  Eclipse is irrelevant here, this is about SVN.  When you Synchronize, Subclipse is calling the same API as the command line "svn st -u".  This requires svn to talk to the server, hence it tries to get the credentials from the keychain.

Comment: The problem is i m using two eclipse (one with android plugin) other eclipse app for other use , and when i try to access my local svn from first one , i m getting those POP access keychain ....., but with other eclipse app it s ok , (vote +1 for your answer  :)  ).

Comment: Did you ever click Allow?  OSX asks this question again anytime the binary changes.  So two different Eclipse's are two different binaries and you have to Always Allow for each of them.

Comment: i finish by delete first Eclipse ( each time i change some thing in any svn project it ask me to allow eclipse .....) ... The Other Eclipse app is ok now :) ... no more POPUP ;) .

Comment: Could you please be more clear about what you did to solve the problem? I use one eclipse app to manage my codebases, others for dev and testing. It asks me again and again to grant keychain access, regardless of wether I allowed it previously (even for the same running eclipse instance).